# R - Number of days since last occurrence

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 id     date
 1001   2012-10-11
 1005   2013-02-20
 1005   2012-11-21
 1005   2014-03-14
 1003   2013-10-25
 1003   2013-11-30
```

I need to find, for each row, the number of days that have passed since the last occurrence of that id. For the above example, the answer would look like this:

```
 id     date        no_of_days
 1001   2012-10-11  NA
 1005   2013-02-20  91
 1005   2012-11-21  NA
 1005   2014-03-14  387
 1003   2013-10-25  NA
 1003   2013-11-30  36
```

A bit of searching got me to the point where I can add a new column with values that were generated by applying a function on subgroups (the R equivalent of Ststa's `bysort`):

```
df$no_of_days<-with(df,ave(id,id,FUN=days_passed,na.rm=TRUE))
```

However, defining the new function days_passed is proving to be tricky as I have to find the last occurrence of that uniqid, and then formulate the function accordingly.

I'm new to R, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a good question on R programming but doesn't seem to have a statistical aspect - is it a candidate for migration to SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I exclusively use `data.table`, so this is an answer using `data.table`...

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=c(1001,1005,1005,1005,1003,1003),
date=as.IDate(c("2012-10-11","2013-02-20","2012-11-21",
"2014-03-14", "2013-10-25","2013-11-30")))

setkeyv(dt, c("id","date"))
dt[,delta:=c(NA,diff(date)),by=id]
dt
     id       date delta
1: 1001 2012-10-11    NA
2: 1003 2013-10-25    NA
3: 1003 2013-11-30    36
4: 1005 2012-11-21    NA
5: 1005 2013-02-20    91
6: 1005 2014-03-14   387
```

Function `setkeyv` both indexes and sorts `dt` on `id` and `date`. Then we compute the `delta` by stepping over the indexed values in `id` and computing the first difference of `date`. Because first differences of $n$ values will yield $n-1$ entires, we concatenate `NA` to the result.

Conveniently, the use of `data.table`is very fast, even for large objects.